# When using Get-AppxPackage and Get-ItemProperty in powershell in C#, the datatable cannot be added

Tags: c#, powershell, winforms

I am developing a WinForms application in C#. I am trying to retrieve software information (name, version) installed on the PC using PowerShell with Get-AppxPackage and Get-ItemProperty. The information retrieved from Get-ItemProperty is stored correctly in a DataTable after collecting it as a collection, and it is displayed in a DataGridView. However, the Name and Version retrieved from Get-AppxPackage are not being collected in the collection, resulting in a count of 0. Naturally, they are not being displayed in the DataTable or the DataGridView.

The code for loading PowerShell is the same in both cases, and I only changed the command values. So why isn't it working?

Here is the attached code.

```
private DataTable GetPrograms_1()
{
DataTable programTable_1 = new DataTable();
programTable_1.Columns.Add("Item Name");
programTable_1.Columns.Add("Item Version");

        // Get-ItemProperty - UWP 
        string? command = "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion";
        PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
        powerShell.AddScript(command);

        // PowerShell
        Collection<PSObject> psObjects = powerShell.Invoke();

        //  DataTable
        foreach (PSObject psObject in psObjects)
        {
            if (psObject.Properties["DisplayName"] != null && psObject.Properties["DisplayVersion"] != null)
            {
                string itemName = psObject.Properties["DisplayName"]?.Value?.ToString();
                string itemVersion = psObject.Properties["DisplayVersion"]?.Value?.ToString();

                programTable_1.Rows.Add(itemName, itemVersion);
            }
        }
        return programTable_1;
    }

    // UWP data
    private DataTable GetPrograms_2()
    {
        DataTable programTable_2 = new DataTable();
        programTable_2.Columns.Add("App Name");
        programTable_2.Columns.Add("App Version");

        // Get-AppxPackage - UWP
        string? command = "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Select-Object Name, Version";
        PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
        powerShell.AddScript(command);

        // PowerShell 
        Collection<PSObject> psObjects = powerShell.Invoke();

        // DataTable
        foreach (PSObject psObject in psObjects)
        {
            if (psObject.Properties["Name"]?.Value != null && psObject.Properties["Version"]?.Value != null)
            {
                string appName = psObject.Properties["Name"]?.Value?.ToString();
                string appVersion = psObject.Properties["Version"]?.Value?.ToString();

                programTable_2.Rows.Add(appName, appVersion);
            }
        }
        return programTable_2;
    }
```

Using Get-AppxPackage is necessary. The data from the registry under CurrentVersion/Uninstall cannot replace the data obtained from Get-AppxPackage. The purpose is to extract information about UWP applications on the PC. To retrieve the list of apps from "Settings" -> "Apps" -> "Apps & features" in Windows 11, Get-AppxPackage must be used.

Comment: `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers` requires local admin privileges. I bet if you inspect `powerShell.Streams.Error` right after `powerShell.Invoke()` returns, you'll find an error message telling you as much :)

Comment: Are you running from Visual Studio?  If so you are not automatically running as Admin.  Right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen 
When checking with `powerShell.Streams.Error`, I encountered two errors as shown below. I tried loading the appx module and changing the permission to remotesigned in PowerShell, but the errors persist and the same error keeps appearing. What should I do to resolve this?

Here are the two error messages:

1. "Get-AppxPackage" command was found in the module 'appx', but the module could not be loaded. 

2. Failed to generate proxies for the remote module 'appx'. Files cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

Comment: @jdweng Yes im running VS, also select Run As Admin. However it still not working.

Comment: Are you writing your application on top of .NET 6/7? The `AppX` module has a bunch of WinRT dependencies that only work in Windows PowerShell (which can only be hosted in a .NETFX app). So if using `Get-AppxPackage` is a hard dependency, then so is .NET 4.x :)

Comment: To debug I would add inside the foreach : psObject | Format-List which will output the properties returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the method of executing the PowerShell script directly via `powershell.exe` and then reading the results from standard output.

```
// PowerShell Process Start
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName ="powershell.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-Command (Get-AppxPackage | Select-Object Name, Version)";
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();

// Read Result
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

// Process End
process.WaitForExit();
```